# What is this result called? Two intersecting lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

What is the name of the following theorem? I tried to google for a proof but couldn't find any.

When two intersecting lines are, respectively, perpendicular
to two other lines, the angles formed by the two pairs are equal.

[image]

Is it a result from Alternate Interior Angles?
[image]

Comment: The sum of the angles of a triangle is $\pi$.

Comment: The bottom right of your red rectangle has two angles, $\theta_2$ and $90^\circ-\theta_2$.  The three angles in the triangle on the right add up to $180^\circ$, so we know that $90^\circ + \theta_1 + (90^\circ - \theta_2) = 180^\circ$ and so after rearranging we get the desired result.